# Adding appending numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm currently trying to append multiple Numpy arrays together. Basically, what I want to do is to start from a (1 x m) matrix (technically a vector), and end up with a (n x m) matrix. So going from n (1 x m) matrices (vectors) to one (n x m) matrix (If that makes any sense). The ultimate goal with this is to write the matrix into a csv-file with the numpy.savetxt() function so I'll end up with a csv-file with n columns of m length.

The problem with this is that numpy.append() appends the vectors together into a (1 x 2m) vector. So let's say a1 and a2 are Numpy arrays with 10000 elements each. I'll append a2 into a1 by using the append function and simultaneously creating a new array called a, which contains both a1 and a2.

```
a=np.append(a1, a2, axis=0)
a.shape
>>(20000,)
```

What I want instead is for the shape to be of the form

```
>>(2, 10000)
```

or more generally

```
>>(n, m)
```

What should I do? Please note, that I want to continue adding the vectors into the array. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What's the source of `a1`, `a2`, etc?  Do they all exist at the start of this operation, or do you HAVE to generate `a3` after `a2` has been created and appended?

Comment: I think you need to play around more with `np.array([...])` and `np.reshape`, and `np.concatenate`.  Those are building blocks for all the proposed variations (`vstack`, `column_stack`, `append`).  Look at Python code where available.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the transpose of `numpy.column_stack`

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b=np.array([9,8,7,6,5])
c=np.column_stack((a,b)).T

print c
>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]])

print a.shape,b.shape,c.shape
>>> (5,) (5,) (2, 5)
```

**EDIT**:

you can keep adding columns like so:

```
d=np.array([2,2,2,2,2])
c=np.column_stack((c.T,d)).T
print c
>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
print c.shape
>>> (3, 5)
```

Comment: Hmmm. The problem I'm running into with this is that I can't keep adding columns to c, because of the shape problem. How do I keep adding these (1 x m) vectors into the (n x m) matrix inside a for-loop? Because at the moment, if I for example want to add an array d (shape (1 x 5)) into c, I'll get the shape error.

    ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: you can add a new column with c=np.column_stack((c.T,d)).T. See my edit

Comment: He doesn't need to transpose the `column_stack` if he wants to create a `csv` with `n` columns.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
a=np.append(a1, a2, axis=0).reshape(2,10000)
a.shape
>>(2,10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge arrays vertically I would use `np.vstack`

```
import numpy as np

np.vstack((a1,a2))
```

However, from my point of view, `numpy.array` shouldn't be created using `for` loops and appending the new array to the old one. Instead, either you create first the whole `numpy.array` (nxm) and you write the data from the `for` loop into that array,

```
data = np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range(n):
    data[i] = ...
```

or you first create your array as an ordinary python list using `append` which you can transform at the end into an `numpy.array`.

```
data = []

for i in range(n):
    data.append(...)

data = np.asarray(data)
```

Comment: If `a1`, `a2`, etc are all 1d arrays, then `np.array([a1,a2,a3,..])` works just as well as `vstack`.  That's what your last example is doing.  `vstack` would be better for the incremental build (where one array is 2d, the other(s) 1d).

Comment: @hpaulj : I'm not sure what you mean ... I am just saying that I would use `np.vstack` instead of the transposed `np.column_stack` in the `for` loop. In the other part of my answer I only want to emphasize that the approach in general is not efficient from my (`numpy`) point of view. Instead, I would use one of the two options I propose ...